# Selection and getSelection. Which object should I use?

Tags: javascript

There are two objects named selection and getSelection in javascript. Now "Selection" has a lot of properties and methods. For example the method toString, Modify and so on.

The question I am having is which of the two versions should I use, the object selection or getSelection?

No info in caniuse.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this--------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script>

        function SelectText() {
            var input = document.getElementById("mytextbox");
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(2, 5);

            var selObj = Window.toString();
            //window.getselection returs the object of current selection
            alert(selObj);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><input type="text" id="mytextbox" size="20" value="getselection" /></p>
    <p><button onclick="SelectText()">Select text</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is browser support anyways? I heared ie11 removed "selection"

Comment: Browser support  IE 9 not more than that

Answer (score 1):

Those are not the same thing: `getSelection` returns the current selection on the page as an object that is an instance of `Selection`. Since the object returned by `getSelection` is an instance of `Selection` it will inherit all its methods and properties (including toString, modify and so on). So to anwser your question you must you `getSelection` to get, set and modify the selection on the page.

Some documentation [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this .. you may get an idea about  version support and getselection

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedText() {
            var selText = "";
            if (window.getSelection) {
                //   Supports all browsers, except IE before version 9
                if (document.activeElement &&
                        (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "textarea" ||
                         document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input")) {
                    var text = document.activeElement.value;
                    selText = text.substring(document.activeElement.selectionStart,
                                              document.activeElement.selectionEnd);
                }
                else {
                    var selRange = window.getSelection();
                    selText = selRange.toString();
                }
            }
            else {
                if (document.selection.createRange) { 
// for  Internet Explorer
                    var range = document.selection.createRange();
                    selText = range.text;
                }
            }
            if (selText !== "") {
                alert(selText);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onmouseup="GetSelectedText ()">
    Some text for selection.
    <br /><br />
    <textarea>Some text in a textarea element.</textarea>
    <input type="text" value="Some text in an input field." size="40" />
    <br /><br />
    Select some content on this page!
</body>
```